# how do I use startAt and endAt in firebase 9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firebase and want to use geo querying in my firestore db. the code examples in the docs use an older version of firebase, and I am having a hard time figuring out the equivalent to ".startAt" and ".endAt".

can someone quickly explain how it works in firebase 9?

Comment: By the way, the docs *do* have examples of version 9. Each code example has tabs where you can switch between v8 and v9, as well as to non-javascript examples. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#web-version-9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `startAt()` method includes the start point, while the `endAt()` methods to define an end point for your query results.

Sample code `startAt()` (Web v9):

```
import { query, orderBy, startAt } from "firebase/firestore";  

const q = query(citiesRef, orderBy("population"), startAt(1000000));
```

sample code 'endAt()' (Web v9):

```
import { query, orderBy, endAt } from "firebase/firestore";  

const q = query(citiesRef, orderBy("population"), endAt(1000000));
```

You may want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74189005/how-do-i-use-startat-and-endat-in-firebase-9#:%7E:text=firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query%2Ddata/%E2%80%A6) documentation about Paginate data with query cursors.

As mentioned by @Nicholas Tower you can check the other tabs for more examples (Web v9, Web v8, Swift, Obective-C, Java, etc).